# Can I access iPhone Log on iOS8 from ICU running in Mavericks

Tags: ios8, osx-yosemite

A few iPhones in my company have been updated to IOS8 and I cannot see their console using iPhone Configuration Utility 3.5 (Mavericks). I can see the console on devices with iOS7.

I really don't want to install Yosemite on another partition just to be able to view logs. Is there some other tool that will allow me to view the logs on the iPhone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Follow the steps below,

1) Upgrade/Use Xcode 6.

2) Connect device to system.

3) Go to 'Window' menu present in Xcode menu bar.

4) Select 'Devices'.

5) Click on device name which is showing in left side pan of Devices window under "DEVICES" heading.

6) Check the right side pane of Devices window it should be showing 'Device Information', 'Installed
Apps' and below that a Device console. If you are not able to see Device console click on Up headed arrow button that is 'Show the device console' button present at bottom of window.